# What is the phonetic transcription of the Lithuanian name Austėja?

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, transcription, lithuanian

I do not know how to transcribe this name.

Comment: Does Wikipedia "Lithuanian orthography" have what you want?

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it this way: [əʊ'stʲeja] (I like this variant more, but don't have any data to prove it) or [əʊs'tʲeja]. It is based on my knowledge of Lithuanian and [this recording](https://forvo.com/word/aust%C4%97ja_%5Blt.%5D/).

It is differ from Wikipedia solution proposed by [Draconis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/10559/draconis) in three aspects:

- I know the stress position;
- I know that the first two letters correspond to a diphthong [aʊ];
- I know that in the unstressed position this diphthong will be reduced to [əʊ].

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Does this mean that phonetically it is [əʊ'stʲeja] but phonologically it is /aʊ'stʲeja/ ?

Also, is it correct to put the s and the t together in the principle of a syllable in Lithuanian? When this happens in some languages, like Spanish, the s would be part of the previous syllable, and it would be something like /əʊs'tʲeja/ or /aʊs'tʲeja/. Is that not the case in Lithuanian?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, it is hard question for me, since I don't believe in such a distinction like phonetic and phonology... But... the answer will be yes. I don't know much about syllabification in Lithuanian, I've accidentally put it  before s. I'll change it in my answer.

Comment: @algo It seems phonologically, it would be probably /aʊ'steja/ (without the palatalisation marker, since it seems to be positional, not distinctive).